# Numpy lambda error using serverless

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, serverless-framework

I'm on mac OSX and deploying a python lambda on AWS.

I have created a local env source venv/bin/activate following these instructions.

https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

I have installed all of the packages

```
$ pip install numpy

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.14.2)
```

then i deploy the package using

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt

serverless deploy
```

**error when running on the lambda**

> START RequestId: ################### Version: $LATEST
>   Unable to import module '**main**': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Also note: my code is not calling numpy, it's calling quandl and quandl is calling numpy

**requirements.txt**

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.2.2
idna==2.6
inflection==0.3.1
more-itertools==4.1.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.4
numpy==1.14.2
pandas==0.22.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pycparser==2.18
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
python-dateutil==2.7.2
pytz==2018.4
Quandl==3.3.0
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
```

Running the same code on an ec2. looks like its numpy is having an issue calling it.

I added the below to the python file

```
import os
import sys

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(CWD, "lib"))
# end magic four lines
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .model.database import Database
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/model/database.py", line 18, in <module>
    import quandl.model.dataset
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/model/dataset.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .data import Data
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/model/data.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quandl.operations.data_list import DataListOperation
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/operations/data_list.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quandl.model.data_list import DataList
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/model/data_list.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data_mixin import DataMixin
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/quandl/model/data_mixin.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/ubuntu/bots/ssali/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: Lambda only supports python 2.7 and 3.6 can you try with 3.6 instead of 3.5 first?

Comment: Is there that big a difference from 3.5 to 3.6?

Comment: I think the issue is that panda can't see numpy as its in a folder out side of the "panda" folder

Comment: I think the real issue has to do with the numpy package that gets installed on osx, but I wanted to verify that it wasn't 3.5 before I wrote a longer answer.

Comment: I'm running on a ec2 now same issue

Comment: Could you post your serverless.yml file? Are you setting `dockerizePip`?

Comment: Hey guys  Jacques Kvam  was right, I upgraded to 3.6 on the ec2 and it is now working!!! If you want Jacques put it in an answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: I'm going to try this with anaconda on my mac later and update the post to see if I can get it to work without logging into my ec2 to publish (anaconda has python 3.6 as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were two issues here:

1. AWS Lambda only support Python 2.7 and 3.6 so we should use 3.6 instead of 3.5
2. Packages like Numpy that need to be compiled need to be built for Linux. If you are on Windows or OSX, these packages need to be installed through Docker. Serverless contains a convenient configuration for this. Make sure the following is in your `serverless.yml`.

From https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```